# How to install pystan on miniforge for Mac M1?

Tags: python, conda, pystan, mini-forge

I have a 2020 Mac M1 running Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64 for Apple Silicon. I have tried pip install pystan and gets the following error

> error: legacy-install-failure
>
> × Encountered error while trying to install package. ╰─> pystan

I have also tried doing conda install pystan and gets this:

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be
> incompatible with each other:
>
> Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Any help is appreciated on how to get pystan running on my config.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue.

I had to ensure that the Python version was 3.8 and then I was able install the packages `pystan` and `prophet` with `conda` instead of `pip`.

`conda create python==3.8 -n your_environment_name`

`conda install pystan==2.19.1.1`